# Running rails on windows 7 with cygwin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cygwin

I recently installed rails and cygwin on my windows 7 machine. Both work fine on their own but I cannot get rails to run when I am inside of Cygwin. My guess is that I need to configure the path inside of Cygwin somehow? The error I get is below and any help would be most appreciated.

```
C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\bin\ruby.exe: No such file or directory -- /cygdrive/c/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/rails (LoadError)
```

Comment: can you see rails when you run `gem list`?

Comment: No. When I run that I get almost the exact same error except it sayys it couldn't find .../bin/gem instead of .../bin/rails

Comment: you would normally do `export PATH=$PATH:[gem dir]` in non-Windows shell but because it's Cygwin, refer to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4918830/how-can-i-set-my-cygwin-path-to-find-javac. Similar problem. Hope it helps

Comment: I had the same problem and didn't figure it out until I saw your solution below.  The path points to the same file, so I thought that should already work without the alias, but I think ruby (from the _shebang_ (#!) line) is using its own command line (`$0`) to determine its location and using that to find its other dependencies.  Relying on the path, it gets a Cygwin-style path starting with `/cygdrive` that it doesn't understand.  Thank you... You've leveled up my Cygwin and Windows knowledge :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found my own solution. -_- . If anyone is interested the solution was to run the following in cygwin:

```
alias rails='C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/rails'
```

Comment: I used this to set up my Aptana Studio to run rails. :)

Comment: This approach worked for me as well.  My path was `C:/Ruby200-x64/bin/rails` :)

Comment: This solution also worked for me running cygwin on windows7. Note: DOS cmd.exe was able to find both ruby and rails, but on cygwin i got the load error problem trying to find rails even though ruby had been found. Many thanks.