# How to install/use Meteor with Babun Windows Shell

Tags: node.js, meteor

so I have a problem here with this custom cmd shell for windows called Babun and using it with meteor. To be honest, I am still a beginner when it comes to the cmd etc... but here is the situation.

So I am working on a meteor website and I am using WebStorm for this, meteor is already installed on my computer and the meteor commands are recognized on the windows cmd. I don't really like the default look of the windows cmd and add to the fact that I have to force it into legacy code mode in order for it to properly work as a terminal for WebStorm. That's why I searched for a more 'feature - rich' cmd and came across Babun which seems pretty handy.

I got as far as getting Babun to work within WebStorm without any problems, but its not recognizing meteor at all like my default windows cmd. This is the error I keep receiving from the console: zsh: command not found: meteor

Which is funny because my default windows cmd can pick it up, why can't Babun or this "oh-my-zsh".

I already tried adding the meteor plugin as instructed here: https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/wiki/Plugins but meteor is still not being recognized for me. I'm running windows 10 if that helps with the latest versions of both Meteor JS and WebStorm.

If anyone could shed some light into this issue I'm having that would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the path in the .zshrc file?  [See how to add path in cygwin.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4918830/how-can-i-set-my-cygwin-path-to-find-javac) A lot of Babun issue can be resolved by using cygwin solution.

You can confirm by running: which meteor