# Add permanently a certain $PATH entry before another one in Cygwin?

Tags: path, cygwin, ocaml

I installed OCaml for Windows, using [this graphical Installer](http://fdopen.github.io/opam-repository-mingw/installation/).. 
The installation is complete, next step is installing the package "depext-cygwinports". 
However according to [this](http://fdopen.github.io/opam-repository-mingw/depext-cygwin/#preparation), i need to add an entry to the $PATH variable before installing the actual package.. And the entry that i have to add **has to be inserted in front of "/usr/bin", not after it.**
How can i do this?
And how can i apply this change in $PATH permanently, without having to add the entry for every Bash session?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I set my Cygwin PATH to find javac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4918830/how-can-i-set-my-cygwin-path-to-find-javac)

Comment: The second answer there tells you how to make it permanent too.